# displaying info in select input from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Is there a way to display the $city from the database into a select input ? using a loop or anything ? find my trials below: thank you in advance

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
//get city value
if($city == 'Choose City') {
    $city = $row['City'];
}   
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="City">    
    <option value="0" selected>Choose City</option>
    <option value="1">Milan</option>
    <option value="2">Paris</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify?  Is that php code just a snippet or is it your entire script?  It may be helpful if we can see more of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use the $mydata variable being the connection code I can add that if you need it. Tis code will loop round all the cities as many times there are cities.

```
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
        echo  $record['City'] ;
        echo  "<br>";
    }
```

I hope this helps! Ask if you need any other help!

Answer (score 0):

do it simply as:

```
  <select name="City">    
    <option value="0" selected>Choose City</option>
   <?php
   //your loop while or any other to fetch city array
   //get city value
   if($city == 'Choose City') 
   {  ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['City']; ?>"><?php echo $row['City']; ?></option>
   <?php 
   } 
  //end loop
   ?>  

</select>
```

Comment: yes so this is how it gets me the info from the database into the options of the select tag, but how can i make it display whats in that field currently in the database =$id ? so the main option doesn't display choose city if it's another value in the database, in order to click and change it to the other options ?